# Finding Prime Implicants and Essential Prime Implicants for Boolean Functions

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve a EE problem and am unsure whether I doing it correctly. The problem is:

Find all the prime implicants for the following Boolean functions, and determine which are essential:
    F(A,B,C,D) = Σm(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15)

Here is what I did.

[image: My Solution]

If anyone can just lead me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Karnaugh map is correct.

- You circled $0100$ and $0110$. This corresponds to the prime implicant $\overline W ~ X ~ \overline Z$, which is **essential** since it is the only prime implicant that covers $0100$.
- You circled $1000$ and $1010$. This corresponds to the prime implicant $W ~ \overline X ~ \overline Z$, which is **essential** since it is the only prime implicant that covers $1000$.
- You circled $0001$. This corresponds to the prime implicant $\overline W ~ \overline X ~ \overline Y ~ Z$, which is **essential** since it is the only prime implicant that covers $0001$.
- You circled $1101$ and $1111$. This corresponds to the prime implicant $W ~ X ~ Z$, which is **essential** since it is the only prime implicant that covers $1101$.

There are two remaining uncovered minterms:

- To cover $1011$, we can use either of the **nonessential** prime implicants $W~ Y~ Z$ or $W~ \overline X ~ Y$.
- To cover $0010$, we can use either of the **nonessential** prime implicants $\overline X ~ Y ~ \overline Z$ or $\overline W ~ Y~  \overline Z$.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, a minterm/maxterm which belongs to one and only one prime implicant makes the corresponding implicant an essential prime implicant. right?